# How to manage data from different sources in a Drupal 7 site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-feeds

I have data in different formats such as CSV,XLS etc. I have to import the data into my Drupal website and i have to create buttons which could provide different functions on that data such as addition,average etc.

And also if i make changes in my data sheet the changes should also be shown in my Drupal site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on feeds module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds

And it's helper modules, i.e.:

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xls

Comment: But what about buttons how to do that?

Comment: I don't know that any module provides that functionality, sorry. You can use Views module to display tables, but as far as I know you will need to do custom coding to add buttons like that.